# HTML tags in RTL forms

Tags: html, forms, right-to-left

I store some RTL language strings - which have some HTML tags embedded - in a DB. When I echo these strings on an HTML page these are rendered correctly. However, when I place these same strings in a `<textarea>` the HTML tags are all messed up.

Here below is an example (you'll need to copy paste it in an HTML file). As you can see the tags are rendered corrrectly in the `<div>` but are totally messed up in the `<textarea>`.

Does anybody know how to ensure that even visually the tags look correct? I am placing this text in a textarea for editing so it needs to be correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<head>
<html dir="ltr">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div dir="rtl">اسحب هذه الرسالة إلى اعلى الصفحة و <strong><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="demo-start">اضغط هنا</a></strong> لتبدأ.</div>

<br />
<textarea dir="rtl" rows="12" cols="50">اسحب هذه الرسالة إلى اعلى الصفحة و <strong><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="demo-start">اضغط هنا</a></strong> لتبدأ.</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**
Somehow I believe it has to do with the `&lrm;` or `&rlm;` mark, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cdeszaq/8pTyv/

Comment: or you could [use a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRNhF/) and [display it that way](http://jsfiddle.net/pRNhF/show)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `dir` attribute of the `textarea` to `ltr`. It will format fine.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyXH3/) of the updated markup.

Comment: @AdrienHingert - Sorry, fat fingered it. Change it to `rtl`.

Comment: Changing to ltr will fix the HTML tags, but it will also align the text to the left which is wrong in Arabic or in any RTL languages

Comment: @AdrienHingert - The bidi algorithms are not perfect. It's one of the problem of mixing rtl and ltr languages. The Arabic is _legible_ either way (it renders the same, in the correct direction with either tag - compare my and the other jfiddles).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure of the content of your textarea, you can use `dir="auto"` in your textarea. This will make the browser render the text either LTR or RTL based on the first strong character.

Both of these will render the internal text correctly:

```
<textarea dir="auto">This is an LTR line.</textarea>
<textarea dir="auto">זוהי שורת ימין לשמאל.</textarea>
```

[See the jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7sLgy0wy/6/)

The only problem you may run into are mixed strings; if one of your inputs displays even a single strong character in English followed by RTL text, the textbox will render LTR, which will display the rest of the string as a bit mangled.

If you run into this problem, you will have to work with a javascript (or back-end) code to calculate the majority of strong characters in your string and attach a `dir="ltr"` or `dir="rtl"` accordingly.

For the most part, setting dir="auto" on your textboxes should work for most cases.